# Android ListView - various colors

Tags: android, android-listview

I have question.

I can do that every element of the ListView have a different color? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Android Custom ListView. And In CustomAdapter Class have `getView()` method,Change your row background color as per `position`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

   if(position==0){
    vi.setBackGroundColor(Color.RED);
 }else if(position==1){
    vi.setBackGroundColor(Color.WHITE);
 }else if(position==2){
    vi.setBackGroundColor(Color.PINK);
 }         

 return vi;

}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make the spacing between successive stripes?

Comment: `android:dividerheight="5dp"`

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` uses a [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) object that is responsible for creating [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)s for each item. So you need to create new [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) (or extend one) and in its [`getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method you create a view and set its background (using [`setBackgroundColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29)).